# How to use syms in Simulink Matlab function block

Tags: matlab, simulink, anonymous-function, symbolic-math

I want to solve the integral of `expm(A*s)` between `a` and `b+tau`, where `tau` is time-varying delay.

I created in Simulink a Matlab Function block with `tau` as an input, like this:

```
function y = compute_int(u, tau)
syms s
gamma=double(int(expm(A*s),s,a,b+tau)); 
B = [gamma; 1]
y = B*u;
```

with `A`, `a` and `b` being defined before. There is a problem though: the function `syms` is not supported by simulink.

Any ideas to how to handle the integral? I tried with

```
coder.extrinsic('syms');
```

but it doesn't work.

thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: You can try to integrate it numerically using `integral`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful way:

We can't use Symbolic variables and anonymous function in Simulink. But we can create another .m file for out function and load it into Matlab Function Block in Simulink:

myIntegral.m

```
    function out = myIntegral(in)
    A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
    myfun = @(s) expm(A.*s);
    out = integral(myfun,0,in,'ArrayValued',true);
    end
```

Matlab Function block code:

```
function y = fcn(u)
%#codegen
coder.extrinsic('myIntegral');
y = zeros(3);
y = myIntegral(u);
```

It works:
[image]

P.S. By the way - I tried

```
syms s1
```

and there is no error here, but Simulink still can't use this `s1` variable:

> Undefined function or variable 's1'.

Comment: I have just found that an other way to compute the integral could be the block "interpreted matlab fnc"

Comment: And also there are [continuous integral](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/integrator.html) and [discrete integral](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/discretetimeintegrator.html) blocks. They can be useful too!